# ClientConnectorError NetworkError OSError при использовании aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, ssl, aiohttp, connection

С сегодняшнего дня при запуске всех моих проектов с локального ПК получаю ошибки соединения. Проект либо не запускается, либо после запуска очень долго работает, хэндлеры ловят сообщения спустя несколько минут. Пару дней назад все работало стабильно.

- Окружение - windows 10 PRO, PyCharm 2021.3 (Community Edition),
  Python 3.10
- Версии пакетов перед появлением проблемы не обновлял.
- Время на ПК синхронизировано, автоматически обновляется
- etc/hosts пустой
- При вызове rest напрямую через браузер отрабатывается без ошибок
- aiogram==2.22.2
  aiohttp==3.8.3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в связи с чем начали возникать ошибки?

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1055, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1040, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 954, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 704, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 812, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 599, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 121] Превышен таймаут семафора

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Превышен таймаут семафора]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Превышен таймаут семафора]
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1055, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1040, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 954, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 704, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 812, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 599, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 121] Превышен таймаут семафора

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Превышен таймаут семафора]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Превышен таймаут семафора]
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1055, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1040, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 954, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 704, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 812, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 599, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 121] Превышен таймаут семафора

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Превышен таймаут семафора]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Max\PycharmProjects\bot-demostand\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Превышен таймаут семафора]```
````